# file does not exists in Command line Task in Azure build pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am trying to use `CMD` task in `azure` build pipeline to execute the script which is stored in `Azure Repo`. When I run the build pipeline, cmd task throws below error:

```
 An error occurred: The file D:\a\1\s\_JmeterTest-AG\JmeterWebApp.jmx doesn't exist or can't be opened
```

I have checked `JmeterWebApp.JMX` does exists in my `Azure Repo (JmeterTest-AG)`.

My CMD task details as follows:

````
**- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
      script: |
        echo 'Jmeter............'
        jmeter -n -t $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/_JmeterTest-AG/JmeterWebApp.jmx -l _JmeterTest-AG/Summary.jtl -e -o HTMLReports**```
````

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolve your question? If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: Hi, Can you please give me some time to work on this as I have been busy with other stuff. Will update you by Next Monday

Answer (score 1):

Repo directory structure

[image]

Power shell script:

````
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      echo 'Jmeter............'
      jmeter -n -t $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/_JmeterTest-AG/JmeterWebApp.jmx -l _JmeterTest-AG/Summary.jtl -e -o HTMLReports**```
````

**Note**: Then path $(Build.SourcesDirectory) is `D:\a\1\s`, we need to ensure that the folder `_JmeterTest-AG` is at the root path and it contain the file `JmeterWebApp.jmx`, then we will not see the error message.

In addition, we need to ensure that the file can open and run successfully, you can create the same file on your local machine and run the cmd.